# nginx (http + https) on the front with varnish behind

Tags: nginx, https, varnish

I have have a nginx server serving http and https and I have varnish behind to cache the apache requests

nginx (80+443) -> varnish (6081) -> apache (8081)

when I serve pages using 443, pages are already cached with port 80 (image references etc)
therefore browser alerts saying there is some encrypted and unencrypted content on the page.

I cant use relative URLS.

is there a config i can keep in vcl so that it uses different hash for https requests.

Answer (score 1):

Why three tiers? It's making your site significantly slower than it need be.

> when I serve pages using 443, pages are already cached with port 80

No - you're just mixing HTTP and HTTPS urls on your page.

Comment: need to make 3 tiers... becoz... I need http and https, I read that varnish doesnt support https, so I have nginx on the front, otherwise I can put varnish on front.

Comment: Varnish might not do SSL, but nginx does and also works fine as a reverse proxy. (You could use stunnel for the SSL, which eliminates the HTTP parsing, in front of varnish instead of nginx if you really want to write stuff in VCL)